# Child missing parent object rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, parent

I have a Task Order model that has many Invoices. I am able to CRUD operations on them just fine. However, I was doing some testing where I deleted all Task Order and Invoice records and then I added an Invoice. Since there are parents available - ie no Task Orders - I get the error:

```
undefined method `invoices' for nil:NilClass
```

for the code snippet

```
task_order.invoicedAmount = task_order.invoices.sum(:amount) + amount
```

The issue is it can't call "invoices" since there are no task orders to call invoices. However, in my invoice model I did include a validation to make sure the user selects a task order before adding in the invoice. Therefore, is there a way for me to get the validation to kick in BEFORE I get to that error page?

Comment: This one line isn't enough to understand the problem. To handle the error you could do just `task_order.invoicedAmount = task_order.invoices.sum(:amount) + amount if task_order.present?`

Comment: post more relevant code. such as `invoice model`. what's the validation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment: add condition to this line

```
task_order.invoicedAmount = task_order.invoices.sum(:amount) + amount if task_order.present?
```